# I need a mathematical percentage for a final exam grade, too see how many points I need for a $90\%$ average.

Tags: percentages

I have a math exam tomorrow. My current overall-average is $98\%$(A). The exam will be $15$ OR $20\%$ of the final grade. What percentage would I need on this exam to get at least $90\%$ (A-) as a final year grade?

The calculation I think for $20\%$ looks like this:

$(0.80 \cdot 98)+(0.20 \cdot x)=90$

I calculated this equation for both $20$ and $15\%$, but I get for $20\%$ a smaller amount than for $15\%$, which makes me feel kind of "perplexed."

Can you check and explain how to calculate this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean 0.20*x in your equation?

Comment: 0.80 + 0.15 = ?

Comment: Meant was of course 0.20*x

Comment: $x=\frac{90-0.80\cdot 98}{0.20}$ ?

Comment: Since your average is above $90$, the worst case scenario for you is that the final examination is worth $20\%$ of your grade.  If you solve the equation you wrote for $x$, you will find the worst grade you could obtain on your final examination.  Obviously, you should aim higher.

Answer (score 3):

You want either

$(0.80 * 98) + (0.20 * x) = 90$

or

$(0.85 * 98) + (0.15 * x) = 90$

since the exam you have tomorrow and what you have done so far must add up to 100% of the mark.